# How does a fragment attach itself to an activity?

Tags: java, android

How exactly does a fragment attach itself to an activity when all I did was the follow code.

```
    public class FragmentA extends Fragment{
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(Layout inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState){
          return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
       }
       @Override
       public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
           Button test = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragBtn1);
       }

     }
```

I am confused about the code above because I am not so sure how does the fragment gets binded to an activity when all I declared was the code above and added the fragment into the main_activity.XMl layout file.

So my only assumption for this is that the XML layout has a reference to the main activity because it is called by setContentView() in the activity. As a result of this reference the XMl file is able to pass on the context of the activity to the fragment down to the fragment and therefore allowing the fragment to bind onto the activity.

Am I correct in this assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've added a `<fragment>` tag to your layout XML, this is an indication that the fragment with the specified class name should be instantiated and added to the Activity's view hierarchy at the same time that the rest of the view hierarchy is being instantiated.  This creates what is called a "hard wired" fragment, which eliminates a lot of the power and flexibility that fragments are meant to provide.  One severe limitation is that the fragment can't be removed or replaced with another fragment in the same Activity UI.

The alternative is instantiating the fragment yourself, usually in the `onCreate()` method of the host activity, and using the `FragmentManager` to add the fragment to the activity.  This is done using something called a FragmentTransaction.

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

transaction.add(R.id.frame_layout_container, new FragmentA());
transaction.commit();
```

Here `R.id.frame_layout_container` refers to a widget in your UI, typically a `FrameLayout`, that you have added specifically to contain the fragment.  This is similar to adding any other widget to a `RelativeLayout` or a `LinearLayout`.  FrameLayouts exist specifically to block part of the UI off to hold one component, like a fragment.

I have expanded this code a bit more than is typical for clarity.  `FragmentTransaction` is a fluid builder interface, which means that most of the transaciton methods return the updated `FragmentTransaction` so that you can chain them together.  It's more common to see something like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_layout_container, 
  new FragmentA()).commit();
```

Using the fragment manager in this way creates a "dynamic fragment," which is the alternative to a hard wired fragments.  These sorts of fragments are much more flexible.  They can, for example, be swapped in and out of the UI, and they can also be retained (which means preserved when the host activity is created and destroyed as a result of a configuration change such as rotating the screen).  Most developers consider this the better way to go, even though hard wiring fragments at first seems easier.

In either case, there is a special life cycle method on the fragment that is called when it is attached to a host activity.  This method, called `onAttach(Activity a)` is your opportunity to interact with the host activity in some way.

In any case, the fragment does not "bind itself" to an activity.  instead, it is created and either implicitly (in the case of hard wired fragments) or explicitly (through the fragment manager) attached to a host activity.

Comment: GEE THANKS for the thorough answer

Comment: one quick question does a view hierarchy gets called and instantiated through the setContentView()??

Comment: Yes.  This is when you specify the layout that should be inflated and used as the Activity's main UI.  If you have any hard wired fragments, this is when they will be instantiated and added to the view hierarchy along with all of the other widgets (TextViews, EditTexts, Buttons, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

`added the fragment into the main_activity.XMl layout file.` -> You just replied to your own question :)

For further information, you should paste your `main_activity.xml`, where I assume you have a *hardcoded* (vs. just a container) Fragment reference. So yes, Android will find the class (or throw an exception if the class -fragment- is not found).

As a rule of thumb, I usually consider this a *bad* practice (to Hardcode Fragments in the XML directly) since it has *some limitations* (especially when it comes to Nested Fragments) and it makes it harder to find "where the heck did this fragment come from". ;)

I forgot to mention: another drawback of Hardcoded fragments is that you cannot replace them. So if you try to replace the Fragment with another one, if the former is Harcoded in XML, you can't, since the `FragmentManager#replace(id)` expects a *Container* (like a FrameLayout or similar) where to put the Fragment, not a previous Fragment.

**Source**: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

**Extract**:

> Note: When you add a fragment to an activity layout by defining the fragment in the layout XML file, you cannot remove the fragment at runtime. If you plan to swap your fragments in and out during user interaction, you must add the fragment to the activity when the activity first starts

Updated Clarifications:

1. > the fragment bind itself to a layout resource file confuse me

Ok. The fragment doesn't bind itself to anything. You're telling Android (via XML) that an Activity "Main" has a layout specified in `main_activity.xml`. When the activity needs to set its content, it parses this XML and finds that there's a reference to a `Fragment`, whose `class` is of the type `FragmentA`. This gets resolved automatically (if such class is found).

Then the fragment (and you pasted this code) is loading its content in its `onCreateView` method (which you provided). This hardwired fragment is then brought to life as soon as the Activity can.

2. What is the `#`? That's usually used in JavaDocs to separate the Type and a Method/Function. Example: `Activity#onCreate()` or `FragmentManager#replace()`, etc.

Comment: hey thanks for answering so my assumption was correct because what is strange to me is that the main_activity XML is a layout resource not an activity so how can a fragment attach itself to a resource?

Comment: Oh I kind of get it but the fact that the fragment bind itself to a layout resource file confuse me. I am sorry to repeat my question but I still don't get it. Also, what does the # mean in FragmentManager#replace(id). I never seen the # being used before so it strike me as being strange.

Comment: You said that it doesn't bind to anything now that is because I thought the onAttach() method attach or bind the fragment to an activity?

Comment: I meant it doesn't do any magic by itself, it's the Android system that is detecting the Hardreference to a Fragment via XML and it then calls the initializer of your Class (FragmentA) during the content creation of the activity. Yes, this will Attach (forever) the Fragment to this Activity, causing a (usually, but not always) bad coupling between both the Fragment and the Activity. I tend to believe that if you're gonna do that, might as well not use a Fragment to begin with. The only advantage with Fragments (in my experience) is reuse.

Comment: Hey thanks that makes more sense now. I know about the fragment manager and has been using it but I found out about this hard coded method today and has some confusion that needs to be cleared up. Thanks for answering.

Comment: No problem, keep experimenting ;) Good luck.